# Playing a sound continuously with winsound and stop it with a button click

Tags: python, audio, tkinter, winsound

I'm trying to work with `winsound` in Python 3.
To start the sound I do it like this:

```
play = lambda: PlaySound('Sound.wav', SND_FILENAME)
play()
```

This only plays the sound one time, but I want to loop it. Is there a built in function to loop the sound?

The next step: In tkinter I have a button with a command:

```
button3 = Button(root, text="Stop Alarm", fg="Red", bg="Black", command=stopAlarm)
```

The given command should stop the already looping sound from playing. 
This is the function:

```
def stopAlarm():
    #stop the alarm
```

So in short I want to loop the sound, and be able to stop the sound any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To play a sound continuously with `winsound`, you can combine the `SND_FILENAME, SND_LOOP, SND_ASYNC` constants with a bitwise OR `|`: `SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP|SND_ASYNC`.

And to stop the sound, you can just pass `None` as the first argument to `PlaySound`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from winsound import PlaySound, SND_FILENAME, SND_LOOP, SND_ASYNC


class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text='play', command=self.play_sound)
        self.button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(frame, text='stop', command=self.stop_sound)
        self.button2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def play_sound(self):
        PlaySound('Sound.wav', SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP|SND_ASYNC)

    def stop_sound(self):
        PlaySound(None, SND_FILENAME)

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do u have to add SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP|SND_ASYNC in the import ?

Comment: No, use commas to import them and the pipe `|` (bitwise or) to combine the flags as you you can see in the `play_sound` method.